# How to use the 2nd monitor to only show textmode vt1 with critical log info?

Tags: logs, monitoring, freeze, kernel-panic

I have one graphics card with 2 OUTPUT ports: VGA and HDMI and 2 led monitors.

On the 1st monitor, the HDMI one, I use the graphical environment (Unity/KDE/Gnome etc).
Using NVidiaSettings, I can use both monitors side by side with different windows on each one but only on graphical mode, if I hit ctrl+shift+f1 both will be on text mode at vt1 like a cloned identical view.

**I would like that on the VGA connected monitor (the 2nd), I could keep vt1 text terminal (ctrl+shift+F1) permanently opened, even w/o login.**

Why? because if kernel freezes/panics/somethingWeirdHappen where I cant use the keyboard neither mouse, the only place I can at least see some kind of log is there, at vt1. When the worst happens, such log will not be stored on the HD, so I have to get my smartphone and photograph it to track the problem.

Of course any out-of-the-box alternatives to grab that special critical log info are mostly welcome!!!

I know it is not being stored because one thing I saw on that log was "dm_mirror" and this found nothing after reboot:
`grep "dm_mirror" /var/log/* -a 2>/dev/null`

How I saw it? I know the freeze may happen after about 12mins after the boot and the graphical login shows up. So I switch in about 10min to vt1 and wait. I think it is related to lvm mirror legs/logs but that would be [another topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498190/lvm-mirror-leg-freezing-10mins-after-boot-how-to-fix-it-and-what-causes-it)

Comment: x will take over all the input; I don't think you can do exactly what you are trying to. If the system is still running you can `Ctrl+Alt+Fn` even if x crashes. If the keyboard isn't working on one tty it won't work on the other so it won't help you much. You can try logging more messages in the kernel and see if anything else looks off.

Comment: @user1794469 I think  I would need another cheap video card to do that right? the freeze is about a HD problem, probably making it readonly preventing the log being stored. I dropped a copy of the log on the other topic I just created (linked one), that kind of messages should show on dmesg already, may be I could keep a log running as fast as possible on a graphic terminal on the 2nd monitor to have a chance to see something? as everything graphical freezes too like cpu and load multiload-monitor

Comment: I will try this: `tail -F /var/log/kern.log /var/log/syslog`