# lvm mirror leg freezing 10mins after boot? how to fix it and what causes it?

Tags: lvm, kernel-panic

when it happens, I see on the v1 text mode, logs like this:

```
do_writes ... [dm_mirror]
recovery_complete ... [dm_mirror]
do_mirror ... [dm_mirror]
proccess_one_work
worker_thread
kthread
kthread_create_on_node
ret_from_fork
kthread_create_on_node
RIP ... kthread_data
RSP
CR2
Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
```

I took a photo and typed from it as that log was nowhere to be found on the HD.

Obs. Some of my usage log:

This actually happened about 6 or more months ago, I disabled the mirror leg and all was fine, but now I want it enabled again, and the problem happens again.

If I hit the reset button, it will freeze again after reboot, but if I shutdown, unplug the power and discharge (turn on unplugged), and turn it on again, it seems to not freeze?
Also I had only one mirror log, now I enabled the 2nd mirror log possible, and it may be helping on not freezing too?

Tomorrow I will see what happens after boot time.
It was working fine, w/o freezes for 2 days after I re-enabled the mirror leg, and today it suddenly happened again.

Comment: today, the 3rd boot after I enabled "the 2nd mirror log" (we can use one or two, I was using only one), and the OS is still stable (no freezes after some hours after boot), btw ubuntu 16.04, may be 18.04 is ok already, couldnt update yet...